# Moving from one Activity to the other on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to move from one Activity to another on a simple Android app code. But it doesn't seem to work at all. Once I click the button "Change activity" the app stops working. Here is the code for both activities.

1.The main activity. The one the user sees first when the app is up

```
package eg.edu.guc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    TextView t1;
    EditText e1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HelloAndroidActivity.this,HelloAndroidActivity2.class);
                HelloAndroidActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
            }
        });



        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        e1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }
}
```

2.The second activity that the button "Change Activity" takes the user to:

```
package eg.edu.guc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity2 extends Activity{
    TextView t2;
    ImageView I;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        I = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        I.setImageResource(R.drawable.kareem);
    }

}
```

3.Here is main the XML UI for the 1st activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Android"
        android:textSize="30dp" />



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

4.And finally here is the UI XML file for the second activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kareem's Photo" >

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.21"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you are missing an entry for your activity HelloAndroidActivity2 in the manifest file.....

Answer (score 1):

Did you import your new Activity into AndroidManifest.xml? 
You should insert  smth like
      `<activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity2"></activity>`
between `<application></application>`

Answer (score -1):

Try Shashank advice. If it doesn't work try this:

Change

```
     HelloAndroidActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

for:

```
     startActivity(intent);
```